# How I can limit the border of tooltip in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Hello I am using tooltip with codemirror , what I want is to make the border of tooltip not out of  the border of the editor  ... see to this link to show how the border of tooltip  out of the border of the editor [jsbin](https://jsfiddle.net/tooaq4oc/13/)

this is the code :
css:

```
.tooltip{background:red;z-index:1000;}
```

script:

```
var cm = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("editor"), {
    value: "function myScript() {\n    return 100;\n}",
    mode: "javascript",
    indentUnit: 4,
    lineNumbers: true,

});

var textMarker;

$('#add').click(function() {
    textMarker = cm.markText({
        line: 1,
        ch: 4
    }, {
        line: 1,
        ch: 10
    }, {
        className: 'marked-text'
    });

    $('.marked-text').tooltip({
        title: 'This is a return statement sfdl glrflg rgmlf',
        container: 'body',
        delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 100 },
        animation: false
    });
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
    if (textMarker) {
        textMarker.clear();
    }
});
```

How I can solve this problem ?

Note : I want to title of tooltip appare at all , so the panding 0 can not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've added 0 padding to your css code.

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wsks4hv2/) what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: No , the title of tooltip  in your case not appear @F1ks3r ... I want to the title of tooltip appare all and the border of tooltip not out of the border of the editor